# What is the equivalent Linq Where code to IF condition in Vb.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the below code with a plain If condition and <> operator. I am looking if there is an equivalent Linq code to If condition? If so, which Linq operator is appropriate in this scenario? Thank you!

```
Dim member as System.Reflection.MemberInfo

If member.Name <> "Person" And member.Name <> "Balance" And member.Name <> "Links" Then
    lstItems.Add(member.Name)
End If
```

Comment: I don't see any code that is related to Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `items` is an original collection

```
lstItems = items.Where(Function(member) member.Name <> "Person" And member.Name <> "Balance" And member.Name <> "Links").ToList()
```

Actual solution is

```
lstItems = { member }.Where(Function(item) item.Name <> "Person" And item.Name <> "Balance" And item.Name <> "Links").ToList()
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply WHERE on a single item? Because I am looking at only one item which is of type MemberInfo and checking if it's Name property is not equal to a specific value. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need, but you can always do that :)
lstItems = { member }.Where(Function(item) item.Name <> "Person" And item.Name <> "Balance" And item.Name <> "Links").ToList()

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Where`:

```
lstItems = members
    .Where(m => m.Name <> "Person" && m.Name <> "Balance" && m.Name <> "Links")
    .Select(m => m.Name)
    .ToList();
```

I assumed `members` is the original collection you want to filter.

I used C# syntax because I'm more familiar with it. You should be able to convert it to VB.

Comment: I think he's asking for a VB solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to do this in VB would be to use query syntax instead of method chaining.

E.g.

```
lstItems = From member In members
                Where member.Name <> "Person" _
                And member.Name <> "Balance" _
                And member.Name <> "Links" _
                Select member
```

The other answers are also correct, but they're using method chaining. Method chaining is quite ugly in VB (IMHO).

Comment: The reason I was using method chaining is to materialize collection using ToList() method. And I don't really like "Select member" at all :)